# Is there a simple way to directly convert Web-based MySQL DB into ER Diagram?

Tags: mysql, web, entity-relationship

I have a domain, for which I got a website created by someone. They have used MySQL as the DB, but did not do a good job of documenting this and now it is a total mess where I do not know how the DB Tables connect to each other (there are still only 73 tables in 2 DB's).

I have the option of downloading all the table schemas into SQL statements, Excel, etc., but wish to figure out a way to create a ER diagram from the DB Tables on the site itself, so I can replicate it later.

Is there a way to get the ER diagram from the tables on the site itself? If not, which is the best way to convert the SQL Schema into an ER Diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [MySql WOrkBench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/)

Comment: This worked nicely. Used the EER from SQL file option, after downloading the SQL Statements, as I was unable to connect to the server.

Comment: Hey Gagnet glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Squirrel SQL Client](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) to view the relationships between tables visually. You can select any table and view "tables that depend on that table" or view "all related tables". 
Also look at the tutorial [here](http://www.ensode.net/squirrel_sql_part_2_3.html)